# Pass username/password to another javascript file safely

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am running Socket.IO and have the server part confirming username and password via a mysql query (run in js), which works great. My question is: Is it possible to send the clients username/password from the clients javascript to the servers javascript file safely? Without a user being able to see the password? The password is already hashed (via PHP) but I don't want them to have there hash to be able to possibly decrypt.

// Edit

After further discussion I agree it is bad to send a hashed password anywhere besides the script it resides on. Is there another way to uniquely identify a user and pass those variables via javascript so my server js file can authenticate them (without a password)?

Comment: They would be talented if they *decrypt* a hash.

Comment: right, I am using a sha512 hash with salt in php, though the idea of any of my users being able to know what there hash is in my opinion poses a security risk.

Comment: While it wouldn't be bad for a user to know their own hash (after all, you salt each hash with a salt that is unique per user), it would be bad to pass this hash around if it means getting authenticated somewhere else, unless you pass it through a secure channel HTTPS.

Comment: Ah, I agree @Konerak I have revised my question with another possible way of thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One typical way that user authentication is done is that the user supplies the username/pwd via SSL.  That is compared to the credentials on the server (often via some hash algorithm as you have described).  If the credentials verify, then the server creates a session ID for that user.  The session ID is temporarily stored on the server somewhere and it is returned back to the client in a cookie.  All subsequent web requests will verify that a session ID that is valid for this user is in the cookie.  If so, then it's still the right user.

The session ID has nothing to do with the user's actual credentials and should be different every time the user logs in so there is no long term risk to the user's credentials with a session ID.  Instead, the session ID is just a temporary token that was issued to a browser that correctly supplied user credentials so the server can know (on subsequent page requests) that these requests are coming from a "logged in" user.

If the session ID is stolen (via man-in-the-middle snooping or something similar), then anyone with the session ID can temporarily access the account.  So ... if you think the session ID needs to be protected, then you need to require SSL for both the initial authentication and all subsequent page access that uses the session ID.

Session IDs can be temporal (expire after some period of time) and the server can revoke one at any time by simply refusing to accept it any more as an indication of an authenticated session.  In this regard, it's a lot simpler/safer than using any real and long lasting credential as your repeated indicator of a secure login.

Comment: Ok, I see where your going there. So if I was to pass the session id via javascript, how could I go about verifying against MySQL? I suppose I could add a field for session_id and save it to the DB each time a user logs in? Or is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: @EdR - How you store the session ID on the server is up to you and what way is best depends a lot on the implementation of your app.  Storing it in the DB is probably the most straightforward way to handle it.  Note, how you store it may affect whether more than one session can be alive at the same time for any given user.

Comment: Storing it in a DB is fine - you will be querying your DB for each pageview then - but you probably already are. You can move this away from a DB quite easily with a memcached of the sorts.